# Can different processes create different files at the same time in the same directory?

Tags: c, mutex

I'm coding a server process that can be accessed by multiple client processes at the same time. Server process might need to create some files into a directory depending on the client.

As there can be many clients connected at the same time, I obviously have a dedicated server for each one (which is a `thread`), so my question is, do I need to add mutex handling (e.g `pthread_mutex_lock / pthread_mutex_unlock` when accessing the directory? (I can guarantee the same file won't be modified or created more than once, so my question is just regarding accessing the directory).

Comment: No mutex is needed. Any real OS will be able to handle multiple open files in the same directory at the same time.

Comment: No, directory access is serialized by the kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the operating system's responsibility to control access to shared resources. It would be a pretty poor OS that could not handle multiple files open simultaneously.

The only time you would need consider that perhaps is where you are implementing the filesystem itself on a bare-metal system lacking an OS, or at least an OS lacking an intrinsic filesystem of its own, which is pretty much restricted to embedded systems RTOS / kernels, or where you are writing the OS itself.

Accessing the same *file* concurrently may be a different matter.  It is usually necessary to explicitly request/permit shared access of a *file*, but not a directory.

Comment: This answer states contradictory things: at the beginning that it is the operating system’s responsibility to control access to shared resources and at the end that this may not be done for a file.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not at all, the first part is about file system metadata and the last paragraph is about file data. Metadata access should be concurrent and thread-safe in any decent OS, sans RTOS/embedded weirdos.

Comment: I have perhaps not expressed what I intended clearly.   I was merely trying to indicate that concurrent access to a directory is typically unrestricted, but concurrent access to a file is typically controlled.   I have said "resources" (plural) quite deliberately but it is perhaps too subtle a distinction.  The "shared resource" in the context of directory access is _includes_ the physical media and the filesystems data structures etc.  When accessing a file concurrently, the shared resource is also the file itself (though strictly that too is a file system data structure).

Comment: @TanveerBadar  What I tried to say more succinctly.  But hey steady on... I _am_ an RTOS embedded systems developer!

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Perhaps the point is unnecessary and the last paragraph can be removed.  Certainly if it needs expansion to clarify the point I'd rather remove it to avoid ambiguity than explain it unnecessarily, but I'll let it stand with the associated comments as both clarification and dispute.